# Help with Bundle ID AppleScript in Shortcut

Tags: applescript, shortcuts-app

I've attempted to make a shortcut that will tell me the bundle ID of an app. It seems to be not working at the applescript part - rather than displaying the result of the script, it simply tells me the combined text from the previous stage. It is meant to:

Request user to select an app,
Take the name of that app and insert it into the bundle ID command,
Run that command in applescript
Show the result and copy to clipboard
[image]

Answer (score -1):

This following AppleScript code will do everything you need...

- Asks user to choose an application
- Gets the bundle id of chosen app
- Copies the bundle id to the clipboard
- Displays a Notification with that info

---

```
activate
set chosenApp to choose file with prompt ¬
    "Choose An Application" of type "com.apple.application-bundle"

tell application "System Events" to set chosenApp to chosenApp's name

tell application chosenApp to set appID to id

set the clipboard to appID

display notification "The ID For " & chosenApp & ¬
    " Was Copied To Your Clipboard" & linefeed & appID with title "Get App ID"
```

Comment: You don't need to use System Events to get the application name, as the `application` specifier accepts file paths.  Since `choose file` returns an `alias`, you can either coerce this to `text` and use that; or you can use the `alias` provided you use construct the `application` reference using the `named` key form, i.e. either `tell application ":HFS:path:to:file.app:"` or `tell application "/posix/path/to/file.app"` or `tell the application named (alias "...")`.  Although, it's best to avoid `tell`, as that will cause some apps to launch, whereas `id of application "..."` shouldn't.

Comment: All that being said, I think you've missed the main focus of the OP's issue.  Their issue wasn't with formulating a functioning AppleScript; it was incorporating the AppleScript into a Shortcut.  As such, this fails to answer the OP's question.